# minted framerule option doesn't work

Tags: verbatim, minted, frame

The `framerule` option should set the thickness of the frame separators for the minted environments.

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[corpo=11pt,twoside,tipotesi=magistrale,greek]{toptesi}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}
\usemintedstyle{bw}
\setminted{
    linenos,
    breaklines,
    breakanywhere,
    frame=lines,
    framesep=4mm,
    framerule=1pt
}
\AtBeginEnvironment{minted}{%
\renewcommand{\fcolorbox}[4][]{#4}}

\newenvironment{code}{}{}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{adjustbox}


\begin{document}

\begin{code}
    \begin{minted}{python}
class ExceptionHandler:
    ...
    \end{minted}
\end{code}

\end{document}
```

One can clearly see that the lines are more than 1pt thick

[image]

Comment: One point is 0.35mm (1/72in), so that seems about right. The default thickness for framerule is 0.4pt, if you put that value (or leave out the option entirely, since it is the default) then you get a thinner line.

Comment: Maybe is not minted fault but if you put 0.4pt or 0.1pt the line doesn't change

Comment: For me it does change, with the code `\begin{code}
    \begin{minted}[framerule=1pt]{python}
class ExceptionHandler:
    ...
    \end{minted}
\end{code}

\begin{code}
    \begin{minted}[framerule=0.4pt]{python}
class ExceptionHandler:
    ...
    \end{minted}
\end{code}` I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvyHf.png where the second block has a smaller framerule than the first.

Comment: Do the comparation between 0.1pt and 0.4pt

Comment: At some point the line becomes so thin and the difference between the point values so small that pdf viewers cannot show the changes anymore. Do you think 0.4 is too much and you want the line to be even more thin? Or is your question just out of curiosity (which is also fine of course)?

Answer (score 1):

The rule is exactly 1pt thick. I show here how to test it.

```
\documentclass[corpo=11pt,twoside,tipotesi=magistrale,greek]{toptesi}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}
\usemintedstyle{bw}
\setminted{
    linenos,
    breaklines,
    breakanywhere,
    frame=lines,
    framesep=4mm,
    framerule=1pt
}
\AtBeginEnvironment{minted}{\renewcommand{\fcolorbox}[4][]{#4}}

\newenvironment{code}{}{}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{adjustbox}


\begin{document}

\hrule height 1pt

\begin{code}
    \begin{minted}{python}
class ExceptionHandler:
    ...
    \end{minted}
\end{code}

% now let's test it for 0.4pt

\hrule height 0.4pt

\setminted{framerule=0.4pt}

\begin{code}
    \begin{minted}{python}
class ExceptionHandler:
    ...
    \end{minted}
\end{code}

\end{document}
```

[image]